# Проблема при линковке winsock2 через CMake в MinGW - Undefined reference

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, clion, winsock

Хочу реализовать небольшой utility-executable для работы с HTTP/HTTPS.

Использую CLion 2020.1, Windows 10, MinGW x64, Single-header HTTP lib: https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib

Библиотеке для корректной работы требуются **libcrypto.a** и **libssl.a** из OpenSSL 1.1.1 (https://github.com/openssl/openssl), которые я собрал  с помощью MSYS2 (MinGW x64) и добавил в директорию с исходным кодом.

**Структура исходного кода:**

/Main.cpp
/CMakeLists.txt
/httplib.h
/libraries/openssl/bin/..
 /libraries/openssl/include/..

Note: Приведенный ниже C++ код взят из примеров **cpp-httplib**.

Main.cpp

```
#define CPPHTTPLIB_OPENSSL_SUPPORT

#include <httplib.h>

int main() {

    downloadImage();

}

void downloadImage() {

    httplib::SSLClient cli("media.wired.com");
    cli.enable_server_certificate_verification(true);

    // prints: 0 / 000 bytes => 50% complete
    auto res = cli.Get("/photos/59326d5344db296121d6aee9/master/pass/8552.gif", [](uint64_t len, uint64_t total) {
                           printf("%lld / %lld bytes => %d%% complete\n",
                                  len, total,
                                  (int)(len * 100 / total));
                           return true; // return 'false' if you want to cancel the request.
                       }
    );
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(Application)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(SOURCE_FILES Main.cpp httplib.h)

add_executable(Application ${SOURCE_FILES})

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libraries/openssl/include)

target_link_libraries(Application PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libraries/openssl/lib/libssl.a ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libraries/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a ws2_32)
```

При попытке собрать и запустить проект в CLion возникает ряд ошибок:

```
====================[ Build | Application | Debug ]============
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build D:\Git\Application\cmake-build-debug --target Application -- -j 12
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/Git/Application/cmake-build-debug
[ 33%] Linking CXX executable Application.exe
CMakeFiles\Application.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj): In function `httplib::detail::load_system_certs_on_windows(x509_store_st*)':
D:/Git/Application/httplib.h:4082: undefined reference to `__imp_CertOpenSystemStoreW'
D:/Git/Application/httplib.h:4087: undefined reference to `__imp_CertEnumCertificatesInStore'
D:/Git/Application/httplib.h:4099: undefined reference to `__imp_CertFreeCertificateContext'
D:/Git/Application/httplib.h:4100: undefined reference to `__imp_CertCloseStore'
../libraries/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0xe0): undefined reference to `__imp_CertFreeCertificateContext'
../libraries/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x160): undefined reference to `__imp_CertFreeCertificateContext'
../libraries/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x56d): undefined reference to `__imp_CertGetCertificateContextProperty'
../libraries/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0xadc): undefined reference to `__imp_CertGetCertificateContextProperty'
../libraries/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0xc2e): undefined reference to `__imp_CertEnumCertificatesInStore'
../libraries/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0xce1): undefined reference to `__imp_CertFindCertificateInStore'
../libraries/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x2ca5): undefined reference to `__imp_CertOpenStore'
../libraries/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x2cd8): undefined reference to `__imp_CertEnumCertificatesInStore'
../libraries/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x2de4): undefined reference to `__imp_CertDuplicateCertificateContext'
../libraries/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x2e4e): undefined reference to `__imp_CertCloseStore'
../libraries/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x2e89): undefined reference to `__imp_CertFreeCertificateContext'
../libraries/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x3590): undefined reference to `__imp_CertOpenStore'
../libraries/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x35d5): undefined reference to `__imp_CertFreeCertificateContext'
../libraries/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x35e0): undefined reference to `__imp_CertCloseStore'
../libraries/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x3603): undefined reference to `__imp_CertEnumCertificatesInStore'
../libraries/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x3d47): undefined reference to `__imp_CertOpenStore'
../libraries/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x3db5): undefined reference to `__imp_CertFreeCertificateContext'
../libraries/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x3dc0): undefined reference to `__imp_CertCloseStore'
../libraries/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x3ee9): undefined reference to `__imp_CertFreeCertificateContext'
../libraries/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x3f80): undefined reference to `__imp_CertFreeCertificateContext'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\Application.dir\build.make:104: Application.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:75: CMakeFiles/Application.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/Application.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: Application] Error 2
```

Судя по тому, что я нашел на StackOverflow возможно проблема как-то связана с winsock2 и MinGW, но вроде я явно указал в CMakeLists что её нужно добавить, и CMake не ругается, что она не найдена, подскажите в чем может быть дело?

Comment: попробуйте добавить библиотеку в конец строки, где библиотеки линкуются. Вот так `target_link_libraries(Application PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libraries/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libraries/openssl/lib/libssl.a ws2_32)`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но результат такой же

Comment: а если сделать порядок таким "libssl, libcrypto, ws2_32"? Может нужно еще добавить "wsock32"

Comment: Покрутил местами, лог значительно сократился, обновил его и CMakeLists.txt в основном вопросе

Comment: Добавление wsock32 в начало/конец результата не дало

Comment: Добавил crypt32 к target_link_libraries() - заработало, спасибо за помощь :)

Answer (score 1):

**Исправленный вариант target_link_libraries() из CMakeLists.txt:**

```
target_link_libraries(Application PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libraries/openssl/lib/libssl.a ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libraries/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a crypt32 ws2_32)
```

Comment: Если интересно, почему порядок библиотек важен, то это описано в мануале g++ в описании параметра `-l library`. Цитата: "It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, foo.o -lz bar.o searches library z after file foo.o but before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in z, those functions may not be loaded". Ссылка на мануал: https://linux.die.net/man/1/g++

Comment: Спасибо за информацию